# How to configure Paypals IPN to edit a MySQL database after purchase?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

**Information**
I have some sort of knowledge what IPN does and how it works and I get a return from Paypals IPN sandbox.

**Here's what I'm trying to do**
Basicially here's a little scenario (I hope it makes it a little clearer to what I will be explaining);
A user registers on the site, and he would be set as 'Member' in the database, and if he wanted additional features on the site he would need to donate, so he does so and it returns him to a 'success' page (IPN) then edits the database making him 'Premium' in the database.

**What I need:**
How do I make the PayPal IPN edit the database for the user's SESSION (to make sure you cant donate without being signed in) from 'Guest' to 'Premium'?

If you have any other questions incase I haven't made it clear enough, please ask them!

PS: I have literally checked everywhere, so if anyone even has a snippet/download for a fully functional PayPal IPN in progress I will be greatful.

Answer (score 2):

"Merchants create an IPN listener page on their website and then specify the URL of the listener page in their PayPal account profile. PayPal then sends notifications of all transaction-related events to that URL. When customers pay for goods or services, PayPal sends a secure FORM POST containing payment information (IPN messages) to the URL. The IPN listener detects and processes IPN messages using the merchant backend processes. The IPN listener page contains a custom script or program that waits for the messages, validates them with PayPal, and then passes them to various backend applications for processing."

Ostensibly then, you create "ipn_server.php" (or whatever file you want to be your 'backend server' for IPN), and have it read the POST array.  In essence it will act pretty much like any other PHP form handler script.

Be sure to take steps so that not just ANY user-agent from ANY location can post to your backend server.

Example code is [present on Github](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/example_usage.php).  There is also a [more advanced example](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/example_usage_advanced.php) and a [base class](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php) providing most all the functionality you should need.

Comment: Thanks, will try it